# Always getting "code_already_used" when exchanging code for access token w/Slack API

Tags: oauth-2.0, slack-api

I'm writing a Slack app that adds Slash commands.

Every time I go through the OAuth flow, when I try to exchange a temporary auth code for an access token, I get the following JSON response:

```
{"ok"=>false, "error"=>"code_already_used"}
```

and despite that error message, the two slash commands provided by my app do get installed on the target Slack team.

The desired outcome is: I get a successful response from Slack's API, which contains the access_token and scopes for which the token is valid.

Troubleshooting I've tried so far:

- Revoked permissions from my app & uninstalling from target team before trying again
- Requesting additional scopes (e.g, `commands,channels:history,users.profile:read` which I don't need, instead of just `commands`) to see if that would cause the API to return an access token.
- I am able to install on other teams outside of the original team I used when creating the app, but with the same api failure

Any suggestions for how to get the API to return an access token? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What framework/library are you using for this?

Comment: Ruby on Rails and the omniauth-slack gem.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same problem now.